# Gettext ignoring setlocale

Tags: php, gettext, ubuntu-16.04

I am testing gettext for a possible translation solution for a project.

I have created a mini-project with the following structure:

```
├── index.php 
└── locale
    ├── en_
    │   └── LC_MESSAGES
    │       ├── messages.mo
    │       └── messages.po
    └── en_US.utf8
        └── LC_MESSAGES
            ├── messages.mo
            └── messages.po
```

Here is the php code:

```
$language = "en_US.utf8";
putenv("LC_MESSAGES=$language");
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $language);

bindtextdomain("messages", "locale");    
textdomain("messages");

echo gettext("HELLO_WORLD") , "\n";
```

Here is the message.po in the en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES folder

```
#Test token 1
msgid "HELLO_WORLD"
msgstr "Hello World!11111111"

#Test token 2
msgid "TEST_TRANSLATION"
msgstr "Testing translation..1111111"
```

When I do:

> php index.php

I get:

> HELLO_WORLD

The issue seems that setLocale is not being respected. I can see this when I do an strace

> strace php index.php

Output:

```
getcwd("/home/antonio/www/locale_test", 4096) = 47
lstat("/home/antonio/www/locale_test/locale", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2995, ...}) = 0
read(4, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2995
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/home/antonio/www/locale_test/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/antonio/www/locale_test/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(1, "HELLO_WORLD", 11HELLO_WORLD)             = 11
```

You can see that its going to the local locale folder but then NOT going to the correct en_US.utf8 folder. It tries en_GB and en

I do have en_US.utf8 locale. (I can see in the list from locale -a)
I am running this on ubuntu 16 with PHP 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the `en_` folder for? And can you try renaming the `en_US.utf8` folder to just `en_US`?

Comment: @lxg That is just to prevent the gettext from loading that one. Not sure it would matter as from the strace you can see that gettext is not even looking in that folder it is just looking in en_GB and en.

Comment: Isn't it suppose to be `putenv("LANG=en_US.UTF-8")`? And you can replace the `echo gettext(....` to `echo _(....`

Comment: @frz3993 I will change that. I know about the alias but just choose to use gettext. Thanks!

Comment: @frz3993 I have changed the putenv to LANG..  with no change in the output.